# Как сделать чтобы всплывающий блок не исчезал при наведении?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

[Код](https://jsfiddle.net/Devrik/h7qp4dj9/14/)

```
$(function () {
  $("#ShowHide1").mouseover(function(){
      $('#exemple1').slideToggle()
    });

  $("#ShowHide1").mouseout(function(){
      $('#exemple1').slideUp()
    });
});
```

Проблема в том что дочернего элемента нет

При наведении на блок (Скрыть/показать блок) всплывал блок с текстом, при наведении на него он не должен исчезать, но при наведении вне его границ он должен

Answer (score 1):

Зачем здесь скрипты, если всё легко можно сделать с помощью `CSS`?

Показываем дочерний элемент:

```css
#exemple1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  background: gray;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

#ShowHide1:hover #exemple1 {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="ShowHide1">
  <span>Скрыть/показать блок</span>
  <div id="exemple1">БЛОК<br>БЛОК<br>БЛОК</div>
</div>
```

Показываем соседний элемент:

```css
#exemple1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 0;
  background: gray;
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

#ShowHide1:hover~#exemple1,
#exemple1:hover {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 2s;
}
```

```html
<span id="ShowHide1">Скрыть/показать блок</span>
<div id="exemple1">БЛОК<br>БЛОК<br>БЛОК</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще можно сделать не зависимые кнопки и блоки

Смотрим пример если надо закрыть вне box: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLgVGZR?editors=0010)

```js
let box = document.querySelector(".box");
document.querySelector("button").onmousemove = openBox;
document.querySelector(".box span").onclick = closeBox;


function openBox(){
  box.classList.add("view");
}

function closeBox (){
  box.classList.remove("view");
}
```

```css
.box{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.box span{
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.14s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box:hover span{
  color: red;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.view{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible; 
}
```

```html
<button class="open" type="button"> Показать окно</button>




<div class="box">
  <span>&#215;</span>
  скрытый блок который появится после наведения
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно поместить всё в общий блок. Тогда mouseover будет работать и на раскрывшемся блоке. И slideToggle тут лишний.

```js
  $("#ShowHide1").mouseover(function(){
        $('#exemple1').slideDown()
   }); 
 
 $("#ShowHide1").mouseleave(function(){
        $('#exemple1').slideUp()
   });
```

```css
#exemple1 {
  display: none;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;  
  background: gray;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ShowHide1">
  <span>Скрыть/показать блок</span>
  <div id="exemple1">БЛОК</div>
</div>
```

Можно и без общего блока следующим образом.
Но тут есть свои минусы, если допустим между элементами будет пространство, то работать это не будет должным образом. Первый вариант как-то надежнее.

```js
  $("#ShowHide1").mouseover(function(){
        $('#exemple1').slideDown()        
   }); 
   
   $('#exemple1').mouseleave(function(){                      
                $('#exemple1').slideUp()                
    })
 
  $("#ShowHide1").mouseleave(function(){
        if ($('#exemple1').is(':hover')) return
        else $('#exemple1').slideUp()        
   });
```

```css
#exemple1 {
  display: none;  
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;  
  background: gray;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="ShowHide1">Скрыть/показать блок</span>
<div id="exemple1">БЛОК</div>
```

Comment: А сделать это без  общего блока можно?

Comment: @LoInt можно, обновил ответ